# Previous Month Formula

Tags: formula, formula-field, date

I'm trying to create a formula to check a box if the start date is last month.  Not sure what is missing since it is checking the box for all records with a past month.

```
OR( 
    AND(/*Feb - Dec*/YEAR(StartDate__c) = YEAR(TODAY()),
    MONTH(StartDate__c) < MONTH(TODAY()-1)),  
    /*Dec - Jan*/ AND( YEAR(StartDate__c)+1 = YEAR(TODAY()), 
    MONTH(StartDate__c)=12, 
    MONTH(TODAY())=1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big change needs to be made here:

```
MONTH(StartDate__c) = MONTH(TODAY())-1),
```

Currently, the formula is subtracting one from today, and you want to subtract one from the month of today. You also want to make it an equals if you just want to identify those records that only have a start date in the previous month. The less than operator will identify everything from January through July.

Comment: I tried that too, but then when the start date is in august it's not checking the box 'past_month__c'

Comment: @jellybean, it is working fine for me in a Developer org, at least in my simplified proof of concept setup. Just make sure to move that parentheses, and it should be good, unless there is something else causing an issue.

Comment: Let me try again.  I don't think I ever moved the parentheses.

Comment: That worked.  Do you think I will have a problem with the dec-jan period, since the year will be different but the month is previous?

Comment: I think the year flipping over portion should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
IF((MONTH(TODAY())-MONTH(StartDate__c)=1 && YEAR(TODAY())=YEAR(StartDate__c)) || (YEAR(TODAY()-YEAR(StartDate__c)=1 && MONTH(StartDate__c)=12)),true,false)
```